# How to auto calculate table rows using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 3 table rows, each row contains 5 columns with input text boxes, the last column is for the total of the values inputted in the 4 columns. I want to calculate the total automatically using jquery or javascript after the 4 columns was filled with values. How could I do this? Here is my table code.

Table

```
<table name="tbl_a" id="tbl_a">
<tr>
    <td><span style="margin-left:30px;">a. Provision of  certified seeds</span></td>
    <td>no. of bags</td>
    <td>per AT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[a]" id="a" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[b]" id="b" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[c]" id="c" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[d]" id="d" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[total_1]" id="total_1" value="" placeholder="total" style= "width:160px;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>no. of farmers</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[e]" id="e" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[f]" id="f" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[g]" id="g" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[h]" id="h" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[total_2]" id="total_2" value=""  value="" placeholder="total" style= "width:160px;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">Rehab Seeds</td>
    <td>no. of bags</td>
    <td>per AT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[i]" id="i" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[j]" id="j" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[k]" id="k" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[l]" id="l" value=""  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="at[total_3]" id="total_3" value="" value="" placeholder="total"  style= "width:160px;"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: By reading jQuery documentation first.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all please google for what you wanted to achieve, learn yourself, try to find the solution. If you still not succeeded, ask question with the relevant code that you have tried and with some playgrounds such as jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com etc.

However, here is the script which I used. I added `total` to the last input field.

```
$(function () {
    var tbl = $('#tbl_a');
    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').bind("keyup", function () {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var tbl = $('#tbl_a');
        tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $(this).find('input[type=text]').not('.total').each(function () {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            });

            $(this).find('.total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/HV3eM/1/embedded/result/)** is the result. In this script, you can have any number of rows, but the last row needed to have a different class name otherwise its value also added to the total.

Comment: Thanks. I just run out of time to explore and do it with myself but thanks anyway for this

Comment: @Ravimalllya why this one is not working on me? Thank you.

Comment: @x'tian can you elaborate? If please provide a jsfiddle or jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

On input change, calculate inputs's total. If one input is empty return, if not assign total to last input of tr.

```
$(".form-control").change(function(){
   var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < tr.find("input").length; i++) {
       if ($(tr).find("input").eq(i).val() == 0 || $(tr).find("input").eq(i).val() == "")
          return;
       total += parseInt($(tr).find("input").eq(i).val());
   }

   $(tr).find("input").eq($(tr).find("input").length-1).val(total);
}
```

Comment: `$(tr).find("input").eq($(tr).find("input").length-1).val(total);` I think this could (far more readably be) `$(tr).find("input:last").val(total);`

Comment: Since only the total `input` elements have a placeholder attribute, perhaps you could call this event function on elements that don't have a placeholder value? `$(".form-control:not([placeholder])")`.